# Why number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Image this code:

```
$em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$qb = $em->getRepository('SomeBundle:SimeEntity')->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb->addSelect('(CASE WHEN (e.title IN (:param)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN ord');
$qb->addOrderBy('ord');
$qb->setParameter('param', array('one', 'two', 'three'));
$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

What is expected result? Yeah, just list of entities.

But what we really will see? Exception: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Why is this happens?

If I add parameter to `where` statement, this code will works fine.

Comment: I don't think parameters work in selects.. or in fact, orders or groups. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Parameters in selects are works, but only when it duplicated in where-statements....this is a bug?

Comment: I did exactly the same query as you, but i didn't get this issue..., have you overwrite the createQueryBuilder method of you repository ? is the problem still here if you replace addSelect by select ? have you tried simpler query on you entity ?

Comment: have you seen this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042472/parameters-in-dql-select-statement-symfony2-doctrine ?

Comment: No. I didn't overwrite any native Doctrine methods.

Comment: Tomasz Madeyski, thanks, but this doesn help